# Plotting from two data lists on one figure from a nested tibble

Tags: r, ggplot2, nested, tidyr

I have a nested list with multiple data lists. I can plot each data source on its own figure, but I am stuck trying to get a smoothing line from each data source on top of each other in a single figure. Here is a code example using the mtcars dataset.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)
library(ggplot2)
by_cyl <- mtcars %>%  
  group_by(cyl, gear) %>%  
  nest() %>%  
  rename(cyl_data = data)

by_gear <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(gear) %>%  
  nest() %>%  
  rename(gear_data = data

mtcars_nest <- left_join(by_cyl, by_gear, by = "gear")

mtcars_nest <- mtcars_nest %>% 
  mutate(
    map(cyl_data, ~ ggplot(., aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
                             geom_point() +
                             geom_smooth(se = TRUE, color = 'blue')
    )
  ) %>% 
  rename(plot_cyl = `map(...)`)

mtcars_nest <- mtcars_nest %>% 
  mutate(
    map(gear_data, ~ ggplot(., aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
          geom_point() +
          geom_smooth(se = TRUE, color = 'red')
    )
  ) %>% 
  rename(plot_gear = `map(...)`)

mtcars_nest$plot_cyl[1]
mtcars_nest$plot_gear[1]

#How to get these two plots on one figure?
```

Any thoughts on how to get mtcars$plot_cyl and mtcars$plot_gear on a single figure? What I really need is to add another gg list to the mtcars_nest tibble, so that I end up with a structure like cyl, gear, cyl_data, gear_data, plot_cyl, plot_gear, and plot_cyl_gear in mtcars_nest.

```
> mtcars_nest
# A tibble: 8 x 6
    cyl  gear cyl_data          gear_data          plot_cyl plot_gear
  <dbl> <dbl> <list>            <list>             <list>   <list>   
1     6     4 <tibble [4 × 9]>  <tibble [12 × 10]> <S3: gg> <S3: gg> 
2     4     4 <tibble [8 × 9]>  <tibble [12 × 10]> <S3: gg> <S3: gg> 
3     6     3 <tibble [2 × 9]>  <tibble [15 × 10]> <S3: gg> <S3: gg> 
4     8     3 <tibble [12 × 9]> <tibble [15 × 10]> <S3: gg> <S3: gg> 
5     4     3 <tibble [1 × 9]>  <tibble [15 × 10]> <S3: gg> <S3: gg> 
6     4     5 <tibble [2 × 9]>  <tibble [5 × 10]>  <S3: gg> <S3: gg> 
7     8     5 <tibble [2 × 9]>  <tibble [5 × 10]>  <S3: gg> <S3: gg> 
8     6     5 <tibble [1 × 9]>  <tibble [5 × 10]>  <S3: gg> <S3: gg>
```

I have tried adding:

```
mtcars_nest <- mtcars_nest %>% 
  mutate(
    map(cyl_data, ~ ggplot(., aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
          # geom_point() +
          geom_smooth(se = TRUE, color = 'blue'),
        gear_data, ~ ggplot(., aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) + 
          # geom_point() +
          geom_smooth(se = TRUE, color = 'red')
    )
  ) %>% 
  rename(plot_cyl_gear = `map(...)`)
```

But it seems to plot only the cyl_data in blue (the first data source in the map function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looping through the two different datasets simultaneously is something that you can do with `map2()`.  This function is still used within `mutate()`. (In fact, you could make all three sets of plots in one `mutate()` call if you wanted to, since you can name the new columns as you go.)

The first dataset is `.x` when creating the plot within `map2()` with the formula interface, and the second is `.y`.  In this case I defined one of the datasets in the global `ggplot()` and the other in the second `geom_smooth()` call to plot two separate smooths from different datasets on the same plot.

```
mtcars_nest = mtcars_nest %>% 
    mutate( 
        plot_cyl_gear = map2(cyl_data, gear_data,
                                 ~ ggplot(.x, aes(x = wt, y = mpg)) +
                                     geom_smooth(se = TRUE, color = 'blue') +
                                     geom_smooth(data = .y, se = TRUE, color = 'red')
        ) )

mtcars_nest$plot_cyl_gear[1]
```

[image]

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks so much!